# How to change cursor shape in qml when MouseArea is covered with another MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, mouse-cursor

There are two MouseAreas with two different responsibilities and one (*green*) is positioned partially on top of the other (*red*). I would like to change cursor's shape whenever *red* MA is hovered (even if it is under the *green* MA), and I would like *green* MA to react to press and nothing else.

Two MA's could be in different files so I don't want to make explicit dependencies between them like setting proper cursorShape in *green* whenever containsMouse in *red* changes. Is there a way to prevent the *green* MouseArea from handling cursor shape?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "yellow"; }

    MouseArea {
        width: 150
        height: 150
        hoverEnabled: true
        cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor
        Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "red"; }
        onPositionChanged: console.log("position", mouse.x, mouse.y)
        onContainsMouseChanged: console.log("containsMouse", containsMouse)
    }
    MouseArea {
        x: 50
        y: 50
        width: 150
        height: 150
        hoverEnabled: false
        Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "green"; }
        onPressed: console.log("Ahoj!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this by `MouseArea` properties or any other ready solution. `MouseArea` always sets some cursor shape -- if [cursorShape](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#cursorShape-prop) property is not specified than the default value is used (`Qt.ArrowCursor`)
You can of course use `mapToItem()`/`mapFromItem()` to workaround this problem (as Mitch suggested). But there are other possibilities too:

You can temporary change `visible` to `false` of overlaying mouse area.
Alternatively if both `MouseArea` are siblings, you can operate on `z` property to obtain specific hierarchy of object suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to do that, at least from within QML. The green mouse area doesn't have `hoverEnabled` set to true, so you won't receive any position changes for it.

A better way of approaching this problem is to use a larger `MouseArea` that fills the maximum area you're interested in, and use [mapToItem()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method) / [mapFromItem()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method) to translate the global mouse position to local coordinates for comparison against each mouse area:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "yellow"
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: globalMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: redMouseArea
        width: 150
        height: 150
        cursorShape: containsMouse ? Qt.OpenHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
        enabled: false

        readonly property bool containsMouse: {
            var relativePos = mapFromItem(globalMouseArea, globalMouseArea.mouseX, globalMouseArea.mouseY);
            return contains(Qt.point(relativePos.x, relativePos.y));
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "red"
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: greenMouseArea
        x: 50
        y: 50
        width: 150
        height: 150
        color: containsMouse ? "brown" : "green"

        readonly property bool containsMouse: {
            var relativePos = mapFromItem(globalMouseArea, globalMouseArea.mouseX, globalMouseArea.mouseY);
            return contains(Qt.point(relativePos.x, relativePos.y));
        }

        Connections {
            target: globalMouseArea
            onPressed: if (greenMouseArea.containsMouse) greenMouseArea.pressed()
        }

        signal pressed
        onPressed: console.log("Ahoj!")
    }
}
```

As you can see, the green mouse area is no longer a mouse area. It seems that a mouse area that has a higher stacking order than another mouse area will block position changes for the lower mouse area, even if the higher one doesn't have `hoverEnabled` set to true.

Also, note that it would be slightly more concise if it weren't for [QTBUG-41452](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41452). Namely, you could shorten the `containsMouse` expression:

```
readonly property bool containsMouse: contains(mapFromItem(globalMouseArea, globalMouseArea.mouseX, globalMouseArea.mouseY))
```

If you're concerned about the code duplication here, then you can use a function instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "yellow"
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: globalMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }

    function containsMouse(item) {
        var relativePos = globalMouseArea.mapToItem(item, globalMouseArea.mouseX, globalMouseArea.mouseY);
        return item.contains(Qt.point(relativePos.x, relativePos.y));
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: redMouseArea
        width: 150
        height: 150
        cursorShape: window.containsMouse(redMouseArea) ? Qt.OpenHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
        enabled: false

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "red"
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: greenMouseArea
        x: 50
        y: 50
        width: 150
        height: 150
        color: containsMouse ? "brown" : "green"

        readonly property bool containsMouse: window.containsMouse(greenMouseArea)

        Connections {
            target: globalMouseArea
            onPressed: if (greenMouseArea.containsMouse) greenMouseArea.pressed()
        }

        signal pressed
        onPressed: console.log("Ahoj!")
    }
}
```

I used a property for the green mouse area, as it would otherwise call `containsMouse()` twice, which is wasteful.

Comment: That works but also forces the user to implement MouseArea-like component once again.Item stacking information is also lost because there is no guaratee that another MA similar to green doesn't cover it and in such situation it should get the press event.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `cursorShape` in the green mouse area to `undefined`, this prevents it from changing the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own CusorShapeArea like below. It will help you to control cursor shape much easier.

First create C++ class CursorShapeArea:

```
cursorshapearea.h

#ifndef CURSORSHAPEAREA_H
#define CURSORSHAPEAREA_H

#include <QDeclarativeItem>

class QsltCursorShapeArea : public QDeclarativeItem
{
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_PROPERTY(Qt::CursorShape cursorShape READ cursorShape WRITE setCursorShape NOTIFY cursorShapeChanged)

public:

  explicit QsltCursorShapeArea(QDeclarativeItem *parent = 0);

  Qt::CursorShape cursorShape() const;
  Q_INVOKABLE void setCursorShape(Qt::CursorShape cursorShape);

private:
  int m_currentShape;

signals:
  void cursorShapeChanged();
};

#endif // CURSORSHAPEAREA_H
```

cursorshapearea.cpp

```
#include "cursorshapearea.h"

QsltCursorShapeArea::QsltCursorShapeArea(QDeclarativeItem *parent) :
  QDeclarativeItem(parent),
  m_currentShape(-1)
{
}

Qt::CursorShape QsltCursorShapeArea::cursorShape() const
{
  return cursor().shape();
}

void QsltCursorShapeArea::setCursorShape(Qt::CursorShape cursorShape)
{
  if (m_currentShape == (int) cursorShape)
    return;

  setCursor(cursorShape);
  emit cursorShapeChanged();

  m_currentShape = cursorShape;
}
```

Then register this qml type:

```
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include "cursorshapearea.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
...
  qmlRegisterType<CursorShapeArea>("MyTools", 1, 0, "CursorShapeArea");
...
}
```

Then use it in QML, in your problems:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import CursorShapeArea 0.1

Window {
visible: true
width: 200
height: 200

Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "yellow"; }

MouseArea {
    id: redArea
    width: 150
    height: 150
    hoverEnabled: true
    //cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor
    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "red"; }
    onPositionChanged: console.log("position", mouse.x, mouse.y)
    onContainsMouseChanged: console.log("containsMouse", containsMouse)
}
MouseArea {
    x: 50
    y: 50
    width: 150
    height: 150
    hoverEnabled: false
    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; color: "green"; }
    onPressed: console.log("Ahoj!")
} 
CursorShapeArea {
    anchors.fill: redArea
    cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor
}
}
```